# Composer 1.3.1. not loading class until an instance created

Tags: php, composer-php

I was updating composer from 1.2.4 to 1.3.1  and it seems composer not loading class until the instance created?

I need to use `call_user_func()` to call static class function but i got error `Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class '\MyProject\MyClass' not found`

I currently rolling back back to 1.2.4.

test case 1

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
var_dump(class_exists('\MyProject\MyClass'));
new \MyProject\MyClass();
var_dump(class_exists('\MyProject\MyClass'));
exit;
```

or

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
var_dump(is_callable('\MyProject\MyClass::myFunction'));
new \MyProject\MyClass();
var_dump(is_callable('\MyProject\MyClass::myFunction'));
exit;
```

output

```
bool(false) bool(true)
```

expected output (as on 1.2.4):

```
bool(true) bool(true)
```

Is this bugs or something like that? any idea what cause this?

Is there any solution except to rollback to older version of composer?